# How to unbind keydown event for some time and then bind it again in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, keydown

I am using arrow key navigation for table. Based on current selected row I have to load some details in a div. after selecting a row it will make Ajax call to server to get more details and load that detail in a div. This might take some time to make Ajax call and and update div. Within this time I want to disable key down event.

```
     $('#tbl tbody').on('keydown', function (event) {

        var keyCode = event.keyCode;

        if (keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) {
            event.preventDefault();
            ChangeTarget(keyCode)
        }
    });
```

I just want to unbind or suspend keydown event just for some time.

i tried to use time out but that is not helping me as i want.

```
$('#tbl tbody').on('keydown', function (event) {
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;

            if (keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) {
                event.preventDefault();
                ChangeTarget(keyCode);
                setTimeout(function () {
                }, 10000);
            }
        });
```

i don't want to record any key event until Ajax complete its job !!!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to cancel any AJAX request in progress when key is pressed, and then fire a new one to get the relevant data for the current cell? The way you describe in your OP sounds incredibly annoying, especially if you have to scroll over several cells.

Comment: Yes, currently it is annoying if scroll over several cells.

Comment: How about using `off` to detach the event when making a Ajax call ? After complete to load detail ,you can attach the event again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag instead of unbind.

Here is an example:

```
var keyNavigationDisabled = false;

$('#tbl tbody').on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (keyNavigationDisabled) return;
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if (keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ChangeTarget(keyCode)
    }
});

function getRemoteData() {
    keyNavigationDisabled = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com',
        complete: function () {
           keyNavigationDisabled = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI you can use the `complete` handler to run a function after both `error` and `success`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll fix it.