# Enable and disable onkeydown event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling, keydown

Hi I am trying to start off with the keys enable and then once a button is clicked to disable the event this so far works fine, then once the close button is pressed I want to enable the event again this part doesn't work I'd like to solve this using javascript if possible **my close button is in another html (project1.html) file and is loaded via Ajax** here is my code:

```
var enable_keydown = document.onkeydown;

$(".open-project").click(function(){
document.onkeydown = null;
});

$("#project_close").click(function(){
document.onkeydown = enable_keydown;
});


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
             $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
            break;
        case 38:
             $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
            break;
        case 39:
             $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
            break;
        case 40:
             $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
            break;
    }
};
```

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you trying to prevent someone from clicking it multiple times before it completes? If so, disable the button instead and reenable upon completion.

Comment: .project_close or #project_close

Comment: At the top you set `enable_keydown` to `document.onkeydown`, but you don't set `document.onkeydown` until the end, so `enable_keydown` is going to be `null`

Comment: he/she is trying to copy into a variable the default onkeydown event

Comment: @JSmith, which is null, as there is no default event handler. They do not set the event handler until the bottom

Comment: true. Hum but the code doesn't explicitly tells if a default keydown function is assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove event listener your function can't be anonymous so that you can reference it later. So define your function:

```
function moveSection(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
        case 38:
             $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
            break;
        case 39:
        case 40:
             $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Add it to event listener:

```
$(".open-project").click(function(){
    document.addEventListener('keydown', moveSection);
});
```

And remove it:

```
$("#project_close").click(function(){
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', moveSection);
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

What you are doing here

```
var enable_keydown = document.onkeydown;

$("#project_close").click(function(){
    document.onkeydown = enable_keydown;
});
```

boils down to `document.onkeydown = document.onkeydown` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks tho This breaks the event nothing moves anymore

Comment: @Neths The event will be added only after clicking `$(".open-project")` button as I understood was your intention. Check out fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/hxk18jce/1/

Comment: I've completely forgot I'm loading the close button in another html file via Ajax this is probably the problem

Comment: @Neths Then be sure that you try to retrieve close button after it has been loaded and remove listener only then.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, I would change your disable handler to this:

```
$(".open-project").click(function(){
  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
});
```

And for the re-enable handler do this:

```
$("#project_close").click(function(){
  $(document).off('keydown');
});
```

The on() function binds the keydown event to basically stop the event from occurring, and the off() function restores the default keydown functionality. You can refer to the jQuery documentation for those functions here:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 1):

Click on the close div and assign keydown function Click on the open deletes the keydown function from `document.onkeydown`.

```js
function moveFunc(e) {
            alert(e.keyCode);
    };

$(".open-project").click(function(){
    document.onkeydown = null;
});

$("#project_close").click(function(){
    document.onkeydown = moveFunc;
});
```

```css
.open-project{
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  }
  
 #project_close{
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open-project" >open project</div>
<div id="project_close" >project close</div>
```

Comment: Seems to have the same effect it works untill it's time to enable it. So to start with it is enabled then gets disabled but then when it should get enabled again it's failing

Comment: can you post a snippet?

Comment: I've totally forgot that my close button is loaded via another html file with Ajax so this is probably the problem

Comment: Oh so that was the problem. Tell us if it was that. Best.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be as most of the answers do work though when trying to add it to the close button from the html file is breaking it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag variable or use bind and unbind functions.

Also checkout this question :

[bind and unbind event in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375271/how-to-unbind-keydown-event-for-some-time-and-then-bind-it-again-in-jquery)